Polars totals of certain columns without listing each column separately
Say I have this dataframe:
df = polars.DataFrame(dict(
  j=[2, 7, 1, 8],
  k=[False, True, True, False],
  l=['foo', 'bar', 'quux', 'bin'],
  u=[5.0, 8.0, 13.0, 21.0],
  ))
print(df)

 j (i64)  k (bool)  l (str)  u (f64)
 2        false     foo      5.0
 7        true      bar      8.0
 1        true      quux     13.0
 8        false     bin      21.0
shape: (4, 4)

I can make a sum of row certain columns only and set others to None:
dfj = (df
  .select(
    polars.col('j').sum(),
    polars.lit(None).alias('k'),
    polars.lit(None).alias('l'),
    polars.col('u').sum(),
    )
  )
print(dfj)

 j (i64)  k (null)  l (null)  u (f64)
 18       null      null      47.0
shape: (1, 4)

I'd like to keep the column order so that I can then polars.concat the two frames to get the one dataframe with totals row.
There are two potential use cases that dictate what "certain column" means:

Columns with certain type(s)
Columns with certain name(s)

Is there a way to do this without listing each column separately?

Are you looking for a diagonal concat? e.g. pl.concat([df, df.select("j", "u").sum()], how="diagonal") - it will fill in the nulls for you.

@jqurious Ah, nice! Can you post as an answer?

One option could be to use the diagonal concat strategy instead.

diagonal: Finds a union between the column schemas and fills missing column values with null

pl.concat(
   [
      df,
      df.select("j", "u").sum()
   ],
   how = "diagonal"
)

shape: (5, 4)
┌─────┬───────┬──────┬──────┐
│ j   ┆ k     ┆ l    ┆ u    │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ bool  ┆ str  ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪═══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 2   ┆ false ┆ foo  ┆ 5.0  │
│ 7   ┆ true  ┆ bar  ┆ 8.0  │
│ 1   ┆ true  ┆ quux ┆ 13.0 │
│ 8   ┆ false ┆ bin  ┆ 21.0 │
│ 18  ┆ null  ┆ null ┆ 47.0 │
└─────┴───────┴──────┴──────┘

It seems like something that could be done without concat
It's a bit awkward with a 2nd .select() to re-order the columns, but perhaps it could be improved:
(df.select(
   pl.col("j", "u").append(pl.col("j", "u").sum()),
   pl.exclude("j", "u").append(None)
 )
 .select(df.columns) # reorder columns
)

shape: (5, 4)
┌─────┬───────┬──────┬──────┐
│ j   ┆ k     ┆ l    ┆ u    │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ bool  ┆ str  ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪═══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 2   ┆ false ┆ foo  ┆ 5.0  │
│ 7   ┆ true  ┆ bar  ┆ 8.0  │
│ 1   ┆ true  ┆ quux ┆ 13.0 │
│ 8   ┆ false ┆ bin  ┆ 21.0 │
│ 18  ┆ null  ┆ null ┆ 47.0 │
└─────┴───────┴──────┴──────┘

